# python re.search() is not matching the pattern,

Tags: python, regex

python 2.7.3: I'm sure I'm missing something simple but not able to figure it out I have a text file and I am reading file line by line:

```
dnsfile = open(self.logfile, "r")
        for i, line in enumerate(dnsfile):
```

each line i am  matching for some pattern:

```
match = re.search(r'(.*mail.*?) (.*) NS (.*)', line)
if match:
    print  "Matched"
else:
    print "No match"
```

I am getting "No match" for all
in file I have following lines which i am looking :

```
outlook.mail.com.               269     NS      ns1.msft.net.
mailxyz.com.          123695  NS      adns1.apple.com
```

I am trying same pattern and line on http://pythex.org/ and its matching but not with this code.

Comment: The lines [get matched](https://ideone.com/rhGhqF).

Answer (score 1):

You have tabs, not spaces, in your DNS file. Try this:

```
match = re.search(r'(.*mail.*?)\s+(.*)\s+NS\s+(.*)', line)
```

Comment: Yes , that is correct!  thanks . in python 2.4, my code is working fine.